# Argument list for class template is missing cpp

Tags: c++, templates

Here is my header file for my `Array` class:

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

template <typename T>
class Array
{
private:
    T * data;
    int capacity;
    int isValidIndex(int index)const;
public:
    ~Array();
    T & operator [](int i);
    const T & operator [](int i) const;
    int getCapacity()const;
    void resize(int newCap);
    Array <T>& operator=(const Array<T> & ref);
    Array(const Array<T> & ref);
    Array();
    Array( initializer_list <T> list);
};

Array::~Array()
{

}

int Array::isValidIndex(int index) const
{

}

#endif
```

I am putting the definitions in the header file too, but my compiler is still giving me this error:

> Argument list for class template Array is missing

What should I do to remove the error?

Comment: `template<typename T>Array<T>::~Array() ...` and so on

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you separate method definitions from their declarations for a templated class, you have to include the same `template` declaration on every method definition, and quality the class name with the template argument(s), eg:

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H

template <typename T>
class Array
{
private:
    T * data;
    int capacity;
    int isValidIndex(int index)const;
public:
    ~Array();
    T & operator [](int i);
    const T & operator [](int i) const;
    int getCapacity()const;
    void resize(int newCap);
    Array <T>& operator=(const Array<T> & ref);
    Array(const Array<T> & ref);
    Array();
    Array( initializer_list <T> list);
};

template <typename T>
Array<T>::~Array()
{

}

template <typename T>
int Array<T>::isValidIndex(int index) const
{

}

// and so on..

#endif
```